# How to play a sound when first entering a webpage?

Tags: javascript

How would I make an mp3 play on my html page but only the first time someone enters? So that if they came back to that same page a second time they wouldn't hear the sound a second time?

EDIT: I know how to play sounds and everything I just need to find out the 'first time only' part of it.

Comment: use javascript for that!

Comment: Don't, just don't.

Comment: Can you detect mute?

Comment: Have you even tried an attempt at implementing the idea or you want some one to write it for you ?

Comment: Alexander that's really quite constructive and helpful, big props dude how could I ever repay you?? 

...

Comment: Learn from the 1990s and don't. Otherwise look up the HTML `audio` tag and read about the `autoplay` attribute.  To track settings, you could use cookies, local storage, or you'll need server-side detection and storage.

Comment: Use cookies to track returned visitors.

Comment: I'd really aprreciate it if you could actually provide a constructive comment instead of "don't." The least you could do is tell me what is wrong with the idea...

Comment: Serious question: Why do you want to make it only play the first time you visit the site?

Comment: It's for a loading screen for my game server and I want to play a 40 second long text-to-speech audio file saying "Please wait, you are downloading 472 megabytes worth of content etc etc". And I think it might get quite annoying if regular active players would keep hearing that every time they join.

Comment: @Hoodlook it's nothing against you, there are just too many bad examples and generally it results in bad user experience.  If its music, users have their preference, if it's a sound they don't know thats coming they could be blasting their speakers for some game that isn't loud enough.  Sound is generally bad in a webpage unless it's triggered by the user, but I like that you're looking for a way to only play it once.

Comment: Most people would find the first occurrence annoying. I would much prefer to read something like that. Ironically, websites that play sound probably have a lower chance of repeat visitors.

Comment: Well anyhow, I'll do some looking on javascript and cookies to use with audio.

Comment: short answer: Alexander might have a point... slightly longer answer: cookies (I think I have to reevaluate my definition of long and short)

Comment: If you're going to do this anyway, I'd recommend using `localStorage` over cookies. Cookies add data to every HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

just so coincident i have a piece of codes that dealing with cookies. As suggested by all from the comments above, it may introduce some bad user experience upon first landing. But this is something help to kick off

```js
function setCookie(days) {
  var date = new Date();
  date.setTime(+date + (days * 86400000)); //how many days to expired
  document.cookie = 'urCookieName=true; expires=' + date.toGMTString() + '; path=/';
}

function hasCookie() {
  return (document.cookie.indexOf('urCookieName') !== -1);
}


if (!hasCookie()) {
  //play the sound
  ...

  //set the cookie
  setCookie(365);
}
```